# Tkinter Button Images not working in a loop

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

I'm trying to create a loop of buttons in Tk while each of the buttons have image embedded to it, when I first tried the loop without images it worked but now when I add images it doesn't

```
def menu_window(self, box):
        """Specific function for opening the menu window"""
        window = Toplevel()
        self.activate_window(window, 420, 380)  # window default activation at size 400x400
        menu = self.waiter.full_menu()
        SoupMaker(self.main_url+FOOD_IMAGES).get_images()  # Download menu images.
        counter, rowc = 0, 0
        for item in menu:  # Create a button for every item in the website menu - on click, insert item to order list.
            food_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(item+'.png'))
            bt = Button(window, image=food_img)  # on click
            if counter >= 3 and counter % 3 == 0:
                counter = 0
                rowc += 1
            bt.configure(command=lambda i=item + ' ' + menu[item]: box.insert(END, i))
            bt.grid(sticky='W', row=counter, column=rowc)  # increase row number for every button
            counter += 1
        print 'done buttons'
        window.mainloop()
```

While the buttons do show in the window, they are empty and not usable(Configured commands don't work)...
This is an image of the screen with the empty images:

[IMG LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Vpc.png)

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Also, you probably need to remove the call to `mainloop`. A normal tkinter program needs to call that exactly once for the life of the program.

Comment: The problem is probably this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function

Comment: My window is supposed to keep up though, and thanks but I found a solution which was adding bt.image = food_image which should save the reference

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "keep up", but having more than one call to `mainloop()` won't make things better.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? I want 2 main windows active at the same time.. I have a main window and menu window which both of them are suppose to be active together

Comment: Because you simply don't need two. A single call to `mainloop` is global, and works for all widgets that are children of the same root window. `mainloop` is the _main_ loop, not a _window_ loop.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information! I fixed it in my code now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the fact that the interface is not updated while the program is running

```
class GUI:
    def __init__(self,main):
        loop
            main.update()
root=Tk()
GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

if your "window" is the main of tkinter you can use in the loop
window.update()

Comment: It's actually not my main window but it seems that if I use "Tk()" instance it does not work..

Comment: Well, what seemed to work is adding bt.image = food_image, some said on the web the image's reference must be saved

Comment: yes, but if your program is running, you have to update the GUI every time you make a change to a widget.